# How to add an icon to bottom right of textareas via CSS?

Tags: html, css, textarea

I need to have an 'Enter' icon to show up in the bottom right of some textareas, to indicate that user could press enter to have his input processed. This is how it needs to look:

[image]

How can this be done? It must work with multiple sizes of textareas, so I would prefer something that's flexible and not done via position:absolute

Comment: Right, I know this will be done via `background-position` somehow, but I'm unsure of how to get the icon to show inside the textarea.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using `background-position: bottom right` and a background image does the trick: http://jsfiddle.net/ybG53/

That should work, unless you want to do it without a background image.

Answer (score 3):

Here is one method, surround the textarea in a wrapper and use absolute positioning on a pseudo-element to draw the image. Pseudo-elements don't seem to work on textareas.

```
<div id="container">
    <textarea></textarea>
</div>

#container {
    position:relative;
    display:inline-block;
}

#container:before {
    position:absolute;
    display:block;
    right:0%;
    bottom:0%;
    width:10px;
    height:10px;
    content:"";
    background-color:#F00;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/kafNg/1/